# How do you Evaluate Field by Reference?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I want to store the variable name in a string and then evaluate the result. I have the following:

```
var @subscriber_key, @lookupFields, @first, @second, @rs

set @subscriber_key = AttributeValue("subscriber_key")
set @lookupFields = "subscriber_key;@subscriber_key"

IF IndexOf(@lookupFields, ";") > 0 THEN
    SET @rs = BuildRowsetFromString(@lookupFields,';')
    SET @first = Field(Row(@rs,1),1)
    SET @second = Field(Row(@rs,2),1)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Output:

```
First: %%=v(@first)=%%
Second: %%=v(@second)=%%
```

Will return:

```
First: subscriber_key
Second: @subscriber_key
```

Which is technically correct but what i want is `@subscriber_key` to be evaluated as well.

I tried

```
First: %%=v(@first)=%%
Second: %%=v(@=v(@second)=)=%%
```

but this returned empty string. If the variable `@second` holds the variable name of the variable i want to call, how do get that value. For example; the value of  `%%=v(@subscriber_key)=%%` should be `subscriber_1234`. So i want that to be returned when i get the value for @second; the key here is that it may not always be `subscriber_key` or a variable that i know of so i am trying to indirectly reference and evaluate the variable stored in the string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) function to build your `lookupFields`, like this:

```
set @lookupFields = Concat("subscriber_key;",@subscriber_key)
```

In your code, the complete content of lookupFields is treated as a single string.

Comment: i cannot enter code there :(

Comment: See my edit comment, @JohannesSchapdick :-) Never check SFSE before coffee in the morning